# How to send json type data and file at MultiPart in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, multipart

I want to send data and files to an API server. But I get an error message saying 'The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

This is Api

[image]

[image]

And this is file code

[image]

[image]

it's my interface

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change request parameter **f_sign** To **f_sign[]** when you sending/passing a file through your **API**. Im using like that. You can try!.

```
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(File file) {
   RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"));
   return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("f_sign[]", file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```